# Why GSAP freeze animation on quick clicks in a row?

Tags: javascript, animation, gsap

For example, I run animation on click, but if I click on the button who run animation more of one time, but very fast, animation in the freeze. Why is that possible?

My JS:

```
gsap.from(".tab-wrapper-item__box h3", {
        duration: 0.3,
        x: "-100%",
        opacity: 0,
        scale: 0,
        ease: "circ.out",
      });
      gsap.from(".tab-wrapper-item__box p", {
        duration: 0.5,
        x: "100%",
        opacity: 0,
        scale: 0,
        ease: "circ.out",
        delay: 0.5,
      });
      gsap.from(".tab-wrapper-item img", {
        duration: 0.3,
        y: "-100%",
        opacity: 0,
        scale: 0,
        delay: 0.3,
      });
      gsap.from(".tab-wrapper-item__box .btn", {
        duration: 0.5,
        y: "100%",
        opacity: 0,
        scale: 0,
        ease: "circ.out",
        delay: 0.9,
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making one of the [common GSAP mistakes](https://greensock.com/mistakes#from). Quoting from the article,

> The fix for this is simple: use a .fromTo(). Alternatively you could create the animation beforehand and use a control method.

I recommend that you read the whole thing.

FYI you're more likely to get a faster response to these sorts of questions over on [the GreenSock forums](https://greensock.com/forums/).